# Как отследить статистику скачиваний файла?

Tags: файлы, веб-служба, аналитика

Есть задача: отследить скачивание файла, нужен анализ - количество скачиваний за период, регион

Подскажите сервис где это можно сделать ?
(в я.диск и гугл.диск показывает только количество скачиваний или я не умею ими пользоваться ?)

Comment: Где предполагается хранить файл? Проще всего было бы написать несложный скрипт, который бы, при обращении к нему, увеличивал счётчик скачиваний (запоминая IP) и потом редиректил на файл. Скрипт закинуть на свой сайт и ссылки "на файлы" людям показывать в виде example.com/this_script?file_id=1234. Уточняйте, если где-то я выразился неясно.

Comment: Либо, как вариант. парсить access.log :) Меньше перепиливания кода сайта, ни разу не меньше собственно разработки, плюс к тому же и менее красиво.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, только для этой задачи не хотелось поднимать сайт, может уже есть веб-сервис с похожим функционалом ?

Comment: JavaScript-ом отсылать события (events) в Гугл-аналитику. Гугл уже сам дополнит регионы и все такое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать один из сервисов сокращения ссылок:

- goo.gl
- bit.ly
- tinyurl.com
- is.gd
- clck.ru
- tr.im
- snipurl.com
- u.to
- tiny.cc
- t.co

Эти сервисы отдают статистику по переходам по ссылкам

Comment: спасибо! то, что нужно.